# How to start apache-spark slave instance on a standalone environment?

Tags: ssh, apache-spark

This are the steps I've done so far:

1. Download spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
2. unzip
3. .spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh

Master is working but slave doesn't start

This is the output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-107 ~]$ sudo ./spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ip-172-31-24-107.out
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-107 ~]$
```

This is the secure log

```
Aug  9 00:09:30 ip-172-31-24-107 sudo: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=./spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh
Aug  9 00:09:32 ip-172-31-24-107 sshd[4828]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

I believe the problem is with SSH but I haven't been able to find the solution on google...

Any idea how to fix my SSH issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set up passwordless ssh. Try:

```
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then restart the cluster.   If that does not work please post new error message(s).

Comment: thank you that worked!!! so let me see if I understood the issue. The problem was that my worker was trying to connect to the master through SSH (even locally) but the connection was refused because the public key was missing, is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Its infact a two step process;

1. Generate public/private rsa keypair.

   ```
   ubuntu@master:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""

   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa): 
   Your identification has been saved in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
   The key fingerprint is:
   80:4d:40:f6:3a:09:32:07:74:25:cc:cd:f2:b3:75:10 ubuntu@master.flexilogix
   The key's randomart image is:
   +--[ RSA 2048]----+
   |o.o+Bo.E.        |
   | ..=.B .         |
   |o o + + .        |
   | + . = o .       |
   |    + + S        |
   |     o           |
   |                 |
   |                 |
   |                 |
   +-----------------+
   ```
2. set passwordless ssh;

   ```
   ubuntu@master:~$ cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

Once both steps are done, you should be able to verify it;

```
    ubuntu@master:~$ ssh localhost
```